# Windows Powershell Locking Up

Tags: powershell

How do I prevent Windows Powershell from locking up when I run a command on it?
I know that on Linux you can add & at the end of a command so that you can continue to use the terminal without closing that process.
Is there something similar for Windows Powershell?

Answer (score 0):

#### How do I prevent Windows Powershell from locking up when I run a command?

Use the `Start-Job` cmdlet to start jobs in the background.

This is the Powershell equivalent of using `&` at the end of a command in Unix/Linux.

---

#### PowerShell Background Jobs

> The easiest way to create a PowerShell background job is to use the `Start-Job` cmdlet. You can specify a scriptblock with the cmdlet. For example, the following command runs a simple scriptblock that gets the numbers between 1 and 50 as a background job:
>
> ```
> Start-Job {1..50}
> ```
>
> You can pass arguments to a scriptblock with this one-line command:
>
> ```
> Start-Job {Param($log,$newest) Get-EventLog $log Newest $newest} -ArgumentList "system",25
> ```
>
> Or you can run scripts:
>
> ```
> Start-Job -FilePath C:\scripts\Send-UptimeMail.ps1 -ArgumentList (Get-Credential jhicks@jdhitsolutions.com)
> ```
>
> You can see the results of these three commands below. I ran these
>   commands in PowerShell 3.0. However, they'll also work in PowerShell
>   2.0, although you won't see the PSJobTypeName column.
>
> [image: Figure 1: Running Scriptblocks and Scripts in the Background]
>
> The output from `Start-Job` is a job queue object. You use the `-Job`
>   cmdlets to manage jobs and their results. You can reference jobs by an
>   ID. In the above image, notice how the job IDs jump from 1 to 3 to 5.

Source [PowerShell Background Jobs](http://windowsitpro.com/powershell/powershell-background-jobs)

The above link goes into a lot more details covering the following topics:

- Using the `Get-WMIObject` Cmdlet to Create Background Jobs
- Using the `Invoke-Command` Cmdlet to Create Background Jobs
- Managing Background Jobs
- Retrieving Job Results
- Stopping and Waiting for Jobs

---

#### Further reading

- [PowerShell Background Job Visibility](http://windowsitpro.com/powershell-amp-scripting/powershell-background-job-visibility)

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to Jobs you can use [Runspaces](https://serverfault.com/questions/10732/what-are-runspaces-in-windows-powershell-2-0): they provide greater performance and less overhead to run commands in the background.

Implementations:

- [PoshRSJob Module](https://github.com/proxb/PoshRSJob). Tutorial: [Multithread Your PowerShell Commands Using Runspaces with PoshRSJob](https://mcpmag.com/articles/2015/08/06/multithread-your-commands.aspx)
- [PsAsync: Asynchronous PowerShell Module](https://psasync.codeplex.com)
- [Invoke-Parallel function](https://github.com/RamblingCookieMonster/PowerShell/blob/master/Invoke-Parallel.ps1)